# Getting Angular FormControl Validators.max() value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I´m making a component which takes a `FormControl` as an input.

In this component, i´d like to disable a button if the formControls value equals the Validator.max() value.

```
this.formC = this.fb.control( // formcontrol created in the parent component
   maxValue,
     [
        Validators.max(maxValue),
        Validators.min(1),
        Validators.required
     ]);
```

```
 <!-- Button used in the child component -->
 <button
    mat-flat-button
    color="accent"
    [disabled]="maxValue" // here I´d like to get the  Validators.max() value
    (click)="increaseQuanity()"
  >+</button>
```

I could of cause just parse the max value as an `@Input()`, but I was hoping to find a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't disable the button based on a FormControl's value.  You disable it based on it's .invalid property.

So your validators take care of Max, as well as Min and Required.  If any of those are violated the FormControl becomes .invalid.  If the FormControl is part of a FormGroup, that too becomes invalid.

So just just bind disabled to .invalid:

```html
<button
    mat-flat-button
    color="accent"
    [disabled]="formC.invalid" // here I´d like to get the  Validators.max() value
    (click)="increaseQuanity()"
  >+</button>
```

Hope that helps.  If I've missed something, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I´m aware that the valid state of the formContol can be used to check the validity, but in my case I´m making a "counter" component with + and - buttons. If the forms value equals maxValue, the + button should be disabled so you cannot exceed value. Thus knowing the maxValue set in the Validators would be a big help